Generate token with a provider
I have the following requirements to generate a custom authorization token:
universal-auth-key:FE-DP-0-570bb6ae-0-302d02150083da0fdf85b657d01f8530a54...dc349f15bc5aa9491

id: universal-auth-key
keyType: FE
keyAlias: DP
expiryTimeInHex: 0
issueTimeInHex: 530fbbro
keySequenceNumber: 0
signature: i3p8v71wbwiyrwm7q3r459hzcyqj4eh9vn7g8q1v0ppvtytuupwe6hh

I tried this:
public KeyPair createKeyPair()
    {
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "BC");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());

            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            return keyPair;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

....

public X509Certificate createX509Certificate(KeyPair keyPair)
    {
        try {
            // Define certificate details
            X500Name issuer = new X500Name("CN=Test");
            X500Name subject = new X500Name("CN=Test");
            BigInteger serial = BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Date notBefore = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            Date notAfter = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10));

            // Generate a self-signed certificate
            X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serial, notBefore, notAfter, subject, keyPair.getPublic());

            // Add Basic Constraints to mark this as a non-CA certificate
            certBuilder.addExtension(org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));

            // Sign the certificate
            ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withDSA").setProvider("BC").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

            // Convert to X509Certificate
            X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certBuilder.build(signer));

            return certificate;
        } catch (CertIOException | OperatorCreationException |
                 CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

.....
String x509CertificateAsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(x509Certificate.getEncoded());

......
String result = createBasicTokenPassword(keyPair.getPrivate(), createApiKeyParams.getUsername(), createApiKeyParams.getAlias());
.....

private String createBasicTokenPassword(PrivateKey privateKey, String username, String alias) {
        try {
            String data = String.format("FE-%s-%s-%s-%s",
                    alias,                           // keyAlias
                    generateTokenExpireTimeInHex(),  // expiryTimeInHex
                    generateTokenIssueTimeInHex(),   // issueTimeInHex
                    generateTokenSequenceNumber()   // keySequenceNumber
            );
            String privateKeySignature = certificateService.getPrivateKeySignature(privateKey, username + data);
            String format = String.format("%s-%s",
                    data,
                    privateKeySignature);// signature
            return BaseEncoding.base64().encode(format.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

At the end I return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result.toString().getBytes());
But when I try to use this generate token I get into Spring Security this error:
2024-09-23T18:40:48.654+03:00 DEBUG 23960 --- [microservice] [nio-8180-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:234) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.5.jar:6.2.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.5.jar:6.2.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.5.jar:6.2.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.5.jar:6.2.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.5.jar:6.2.5]
    at 

Looks like the way I generate manually the token is incorrect. How can I fix my code?

Are you using Spring Authorization Server? If so, then you have to implement oAuth2TokenCustomizer. Then you need to use the keyType, keyAlias etc. attributes mentioned by you as claims. Finally, you would need to register the token customizer class as a spring bean in the configuration class.

No, I'm using custom native solution.

I believe token generation might not be the problem.. Based on the exception "org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException", it seems your provider is not getting registered properly.

yes, any idea how to fix this?

Please refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider, you need to implement a custom authentication provider and then register it in the web security config file.
